# Finding an integral using mean value problem

Tags: integration

$$ I= \int_{l-a}^{l+a} \sin^2x \,dx$$

I was trying to solve this integral with an additional condition $a\ll l$

In that case I can't apply the condition in the integration first because I would get zero.

In the result one has got:

$I = 2a \sin^2l$

How did they get 2a?

Comment: They used that $\sin^2(x)$ is approximately $\sin^2 l$ for $x\in[l-a, l+a]$

Comment: @MarianG. It is surely meant as an approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_{l-a}^{l+a} \sin^2x \,dx \approx \int_{l-a}^{l+a} \sin^2 l \,dx = \sin^2 l\int_{l-a}^{l+a} \,dx = 2a\sin^2(l)
$$